# Still possible to upload ReactJS app to App store?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, app-store, progressive-web-apps, appstore-approval

Im currently developing a ReactJS (PWA) application that is intended for both web and mobile. 
For iOS, I planned to build a simple app in Xcode with a WKWebView browser pointing to the web version of the app, and then upload it to App store for distribution. Im planning on doing same thing for Google Play.

But after reading up a bit on articles/posts from 2019 on this subject, PWAs uploaded to App store seems to be rejected by Apple as they are not a native mobile app...

Is this still true today in 2020? 
If so, are there any work arounds or is converting my ReactJS app to React Native the only way to App store..?

Appreciate any help on this topic!